# Instead of login form show blue screen with eternal loading indicator?

Tags: windows-10, login

- My PC did not show anymore the forms to enter username and password
  on keypress or ctrl-alt-del
- Shift-Reboot did not bring it in safe modus
- Turning it off 3 times did bring it in safe modus
- Repair Start Up problems brought it could not be repaired with repair startup
- Booted in Safe Mode with Network modus and ran netcplwiz , changing options here did not help
- Changed in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
  to always need ctrl-alt-del:
- NOW i can press CTRL-ALT-DEL this brings me to the next quest:
- This shows a blue screen with the white circled progress indicator but although leaving it there for hours, this never end. At some times it jumps back to the login screen, when pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL it ends up on the blue screen with the white circled progress indicator spinning
- So ... although i checked items like startup locations and eventlog I can not directly see WHAT is causing the eternal waiting indicator... if I know this I am one step closer to solving this
- In safe mode: When I choose solve problems with Windows update it tells me that service registration is missing or damaged. It tells me it fixed it.
- On reboot (and entering the long bitbucket id for the nth time) the same result
- It seems that there is a problem with Windows Update itself causing the eternal loading indicator (this is though an hypothesis since i am running in safe modus). When I go to settings > Windows Update it also shows and eternal loading bar at the top
- I ran dsm /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and sfc /scannow, reboot, this offers no solution
- I deleted windows\softwaredistribution folder, tried to start net start wuauserv but "this can not be started in safe mode", reboot , does not solve the problem
- downloaded wsus offline update and ran it + disabled every startup item : nogo still blue screen with eternal rotating circle
- I think it might be something else as an update CTRL-ALT-DEL bring the blue screen with the eternal rotating white dotted progress indicator circle so does not bring up the form yet to enter a user. Something goes wrong there
- ?

Comment: I do not think it is an update.  Start in Safe Mode with Networking and see if you can run a Windows 10 Repair Install. If it runs, use the Second Link on the page and use the option to Keep Everything . You MUST have a current backup of documents before you start.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I tried repair install at step 5 above. but it got me no further.

Comment: Something is badly broken, so make sure you have a backup and then reinstall Windowss